# java.io.FileNotFoundException for unsplash API

Tags: java, api, httprequest

this my code for HTTP request of unsplash API
the HTTP run successfully when opening in the browser but in HTTP request in java, I have this problem

how  I can solve this problem

note: this code run successfully with Instagram API

```
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.i("ttttttrrrraaaaiiiinnn", "Getting access token");
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id=***");
                    Log.i("", "Send GET url liked image" + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write("url");
                    writer.flush();
                    String response = Utils.streamToString(urlConnection
                            .getInputStream());
                    Log.i("", "*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*? response *?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?*?" + response);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response)
                            .nextValue();

                    tv.setText(jsonObj.toString());



                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();
```

Error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id=****
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:260)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at com.ksucs.graduationproject.myinterests.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the restful api only support `GET` access,you should change the method of the request/remove the line of setRequestMethod(...).and you can't write something to the server,so you must remove `out` variable and relative statement lines.

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");//by default is GET
```